# gazebo usage of textures / pictures

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a model of robot arm in simulation with checkerboards on it for image recognition. For this I use the simple arm model. Is there somewhere a good description of all the possibilities of urdf / gazebo models?  Because I found from a presentation that you can use for instance patterns:

```
 <material name="pattern">
    <texture filename="package://roscon_urdf/logo.jpg"/>
</material>
```

But I could not find this back in the documentation..it did not load either:

```
 Warning [parser.cc:458] XML Attribute[name] in element[material] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Error [parser.cc:566] XML Element[texture], child of element[material] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[material]
Error [parser.cc:557] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:340] Unable to parse sdf element[gazebo]
Error [parser.cc:299] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1099] Unable to read sdf string
```

The material script line from the simple_arm was replaced with the code above. Loaded with

```
 rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file simple_arm.model -gazebo -model box
```

What are the differences between .model .urdf and .sdf files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49643/gazebo-usage-of-textures-/-pictures/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-03**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. To make sure the right people get notified about your question, always tag it appropriately. Also, consider asking it on http://answers.gazebosim.org/

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-12-03**:
Thanks for your response, tags added. At which part does this post not comply with the guidelines?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-03**:
Just the tags... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A description of the SDF format can be found [here](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.0.html)
while the URDF format is described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML).

The code fragment you have presented looks identical to the material statements found in the materials.urdf.xacro file in PR2_description.  If you just want to add a texture to an existing model you may have to create a modified ogre3D material script.  I believe the current (fuerte) script is in simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.0.2/Media/materials/scripts

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0